# Facebook giving Erorr

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get an Graph Request from outside Facebook (just to have a full-url for my like button) but Facebook tells me I've sent too many API requests (altho it was just my first trial), this is what I do:

```
function getUrlData($url) {
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
        die('CURL is not installed!');
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}

if(!is_mobile() && $fangateURL != '') {
        $url                = trim("https://graph.facebook.com/".$fangateURL);
        $facebook_graph     = json_decode(getUrlData($url));
        $facebookLikeUrl    = $facebook_graph->link;
}
```

The URL is the real graph URL and if I open it, I'll see all my data. But if my server "opens" it, I get this guy:

object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["error"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (3) { ["message"]=> string(38) "(#4) Application request limit reached" ["type"]=> string(14) "OAuthException" ["code"]=> int(4) } }

What can I do?

Comment: You can send fewer requests? Incidentally, fangates are no longer permitted by Facebook policy.

Comment: It's not a Fangate, I just want to get the Full Fan Page URL out of the Fan Page ID to place into my FacebooK Like Button's "data-href"...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your server is making too many calls to the API.

> CODE: 4
>
> NAME: API Too Many Calls
>
> WHAT TO DO: Temporary issue due to throttling - retry the operation after waiting and examine your API request volume.

Sounds like some were on your server there are too many other calls being made. The limit is, I read somewhere but can't find at the moment, 600 calls per 600 seconds per token & per IP then a 2 minute timeout.

Here's the documentation to batch requests. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/

Comment: My server never ever sent any API call... so strange

Comment: How did you get the error message if you never sent any API calls?

Comment: It's the first time I sent the request. If I open the script once, how can I have sent more than 1 request?